# Traffic light semaphore using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, frame

I am trying to build a traffic light semaphore using threads but I can't get right.Semaphore should display red, yellow, green with break between colors. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.
Here is my code...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StopTheLights extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton start;
    JButton stop;
        JPanel panel;
    Boolean flag;

    public StopTheLights(String title) {
                Container c = getContentPane();

        start = new JButton("Start");
        stop = new JButton("Stop");

        start.addActionListener(this);
        stop.addActionListener(this);

        panel= new JPanel();
        panel.add(start);
        panel.add(stop);

        c.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setSize(300, 450);                     
        setVisible(true);
        setLocation(200,200);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawOval(50,50,100,100);
        g.drawOval(50,155,100,100);
        g.drawOval(50,260,100,100);
    }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == start){
            flag = true;
            new ThreadExtend(this).start();
        }else{
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    public class ThreadExtend extends Thread {
        Graphics g;
        JFrame frame;

        public ThreadExtend(JFrame frame){
            this.frame = frame;
            g = frame.getGraphics();
        }
        public void run(){
            while(flag) {
                try{
                    paintRed(g);
                    if(!flag) {
                        break;
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    paintAmber(g);
                    if(!flag) {
                    break;
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    paintGreen(g);
                    if(!flag){
                        break;
                    }


                 }catch(InterruptedException e) {

               }
            }

        }

    }
    public void paintRed(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(new Color(255,0,0));
        g.fillOval(52, 52, 96, 96);
            g.fillOval(52, 52, 96, 96);
        g.fillOval(52, 262, 96, 96);

    }
    public void paintAmber(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(new Color(250,170,0));
        g.fillOval(52, 157, 96, 96);
            g.fillOval(52, 52, 96, 96);
        g.fillOval(52, 262, 96, 96);

    }
    public void paintGreen(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(new Color(0,250,0));
        g.fillOval(52, 262, 96, 96);
            g.fillOval(52, 52, 96, 96);
        g.fillOval(52, 157, 96, 96);

    }
         public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StopTheLights();

    }


}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here.

- Your Thread does not wait after showing Green light.
- You paint all the lights in all the methods calls, which is not needed.
- You don't change the color when "*closing*" other lights.

I did some fixing in your code, and now it works:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StopTheLights extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton start;
    JButton stop;
    Boolean i;
    //create constructor method
    public StopTheLights(String title) {
            // create Start button
            start = new JButton("Start");
            //create Stop button
            stop = new JButton("Stop");
            //add Action listeners
            start.addActionListener(this);
            stop.addActionListener(this);
            //create new Button Panel
            JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
            buttonPanel.add(start);
            buttonPanel.add(stop);
            Container c = getContentPane();
            c.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            setSize(200, 425);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setResizable(false);
            setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval(50,50,100,100);
            g.fillOval(50,155,100,100);
            g.fillOval(50,260,100,100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new StopTheLights("Stop The Lights");

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(e.getSource() == start){
                    i = true;
                    new ThreadExtend(this).start();
            }else{
                    i = false;
            }
    }
    public class ThreadExtend extends Thread {
            Graphics g;
            JFrame frame;

            public ThreadExtend(JFrame frame){
                    this.frame = frame;
                    g = frame.getGraphics();
            }
            public void run(){
                    while(i) {
                            try{
                                    red(g);
                                    if(!i) {
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                    amber(g);
                                    if(!i) {
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                    green(g);
                                    if(!i){
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);


                             }catch(InterruptedException e) {
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                    }
            }

    }
    public void red(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval(52, 262, 96, 96);
            g.setColor(new Color(255,0,0));
            g.fillOval(52, 52, 96, 96);
    }
    public void amber(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval(52, 52, 96, 96);
            g.setColor(new Color(250,170,0));
            g.fillOval(52, 157, 96, 96);
    }
    public void green(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval(52, 157, 96, 96);
            g.setColor(new Color(0,250,0));
            g.fillOval(52, 262, 96, 96);
    }

}
```